# Use of constraints in R

Tags: r, constraints

Simple one here, i once knew this but it has been lost over the years.

Simple equation easy to code in R:

```
f(x,y) = 2x^2 + 4y^2 + 6x - 8y + 15
```

And i have constraints of `x > 1` and `y > -1`.

I cant for the life of me remember how to write the constraints properly in R and the book i have is no use

Cheers for any help

Looking for the minimum and maximum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define your function that takes a single vector of arguments:

```
myfun <- function(xy) { 
  x <- xy[1] 
  y <- xy[2] 

  2*x^2 + 4*y^2 + 6*x - 8*y + 15
}
```

Supply starting values to `optim` and specify your lower bounds for `x` and `y`:

```
starting_values <- c(0, 0)
optim(starting_values, myfun, lower=c(1, -1), method='L-BFGS-B')
```

`optim` output:

```
$par
[1] 1 1

$value
[1] 19

$counts
function gradient 
       2        2 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```